# How to count the no.of rows in a table?

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried this to get the count of rows. But the program is hanging.

```
private int countbaglist()
{
    int count = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = datasource.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
        "select count(*) from shoplist where itemname=?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf("itemname") });

    while(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        count = cursor.getCount();
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hanging because your `while` loop never exits. Replace the `while` with a one-time `if` check instead. Also, note that you need to read **the integer value** returned from the `COUNT` query, rather than the cursor's row count which will always be 1.

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    count = cursor.getInt(0);
```

Comment: Downvoter, explain yourself. My answer is the only correct one so far.

Comment: cursor.getInt(0); it's return no of row in a table? or cursor.getCount(); it's return no of row in a table? explain how it works..!

Comment: `cursor.getInt(0)` returns the integer result of the query, `COUNT(*)`, which is the number of items in the table. `cursor.getCount()` returns the number of rows **returned by the query**, which is totally different.

Comment: @imrankhan  because it was wrong, until I pointed out your mistake and then you fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

try this link for your answer

[How to get the row count of a query in Android using SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351606/how-to-get-the-row-count-of-a-query-in-android-using-sqlite)

remove the while condition in your code below:

```
  while(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    count = cursor.getCount();
  }
```

replace below code:

```
count = cursor.getInt(0)
```

Comment: `Cursor.getCount()` you cant call method with Cursor class itself, you have to create object of it

Comment: -1 cursor.getCount() will return 1 (the number of rows returned by the `COUNT` query), which is wrong.