# How to make new layout for each rowId in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout

I have linearlayout in XML with 5 textviews and some other elements (progressbar, buttons etc.). All these elements are based on data from SQLite database. I can place the data to layout, but how can I make the app to create new linearlayout with all elements each time when user writes new row in database?

Also, how can I get number of rowId's that are in database?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that... Do you have some idea to get number of row id's that are in the database?

Comment: Does [this question and answer combo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351606/how-to-get-the-row-count-of-a-query-in-android-using-sqlite) help?

Comment: Ok, adding the info as an answer to help anyone else who comes across this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) to show a potentially-varying number of identically-laid-out rows. You can retrieve the row count of a database query using the `getCount` method of `Cursor` (see e.g. [How to get the row count of a query in Android using SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351606/how-to-get-the-row-count-of-a-query-in-android-using-sqlite))